# Java sockets - Is explicit feedback from client side required?

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

I am making a client-server application in Java. Do I need to explicitly send confirmation to the server for every message received from the client side, or will an exception be thrown on the server side every time something goes wrong during transmission? Can I rely on a simple try-catch block in the server code and assume that every message sent without throwing exceptions was delivered?

Comment: Not if you are using TCP, it will take care of the data flux control and ordering automatically. If you are using UDP, on the other hand, then yes, you have to do everything manually with UDP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you're doing. If you're just streaming data from one peer to another, just send it as fast as possible in one direction, with maybe a final acknowledgement in the other direction when you're done. If what you're doing is transactional in nature there should certainly be a response to every request.